# find the total number of subarrays with the ratio of 0's and 1's equal to x:y

Tags: c++, arrays, sub-array, prefix-sum

*question*

**given an array of elements 0, 1, 2 with  find the total number of subarrays with the ratio of 0's and 1's equal to x:y.**

input

---

5

---

1 1

---

0 1 2 0 1

---

output
6

---

\\5 is the size of array 0 1 2 0 1 are elements of the array 1 1 is x and y and now we have to find the subarrays whose counts of 0's and 1's ratio is equal to x and y that is 1 1
\\

---

here is my approach but it is not giving correct and it gives output 7 rather than 6

---

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n, x, y;
vector<int> a;
vector<long long> prefix;
map<long long, int> freq;

int main() {
    cin >> n;
    cin >> x >> y;

    a.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i]==0) a[i] = y;
        else if( a[i]==0){
            a[i]=0;
        }
        else a[i] = -x;
    }

    prefix.resize(n+1); prefix[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        prefix[i+1] = prefix[i] + a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) freq[prefix[i]]++;
    long long ans = 0;
    for (pair<long long, int> p : freq) {
        ans += (long long) p.second * (p.second-1) / 2;
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: please provide the solution also with explanation please,

Comment: SO is not a homework / write an answer service.  You need to show some effort and post your best attempt then we might be able to help.

Comment: ok sir i have added my own wrong code now sir help me.

Comment: what is `x:y` ? which part of the input is `x` and `y` ? Why is the correct answer for the example 6 ?

Comment: 5 is size of array  0 1 2 0 1 are elements of the array   1 1 is x and y and now we have to find the subarrays who's counts of 0's and 1's ratio is equal to x and y that is   1 1;

Comment: bits/stdc++.h is very common in my peer group it includes all header files that we want like vector queue string algorithms like these are automatically included in it thatswhy  sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the order you read your inputs is different than what you describe, then your transform of the input values make no sense.

```
//... 

cin >> n;
cin >> x >> y;  // program expects x then y, then contents of array.

a.resize(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
    if (a[i]==0) a[i] = y;
    else if( a[i]==0){       ∕/ case a[i] == 0 was already tested for
                             // on line above. 
        a[i]=0;
    }
    else a[i] = -x;
}

//...
```

You should sort this out first.

Comment: sir it was my mistake while writing the input we have to take x and y just  after n .